# Unable to stop appium server programmatically

Tags: macos, appium, lsof

I am using this command to stop the Appium server :

```
 kill $(lsof -t -i: 10723)
```

But now it is not working.

Comment: could you please share your running code

Answer (score 0):

Avoid hardcoding pid, port, address, etc. Search by **process name** (Appium):

`kill -9 $(ps -A | grep -m1 Appium | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: Thanks I need to close that particular port thats y I am passing the value of port